# Elasticsearch access the size of a certain field in the documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that with field `_size` we can tell Elasticsearch to store the size of the document. This is the mapping that I defined for my index:

```
'{
   "mappings":{
      "_default_":{
         "_size":{
            "enabled":true,
            "store":true
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

The `_size` field gives the whole document's size where as I want only a certain field's size.

For example suppose we have two fields in the mapping. `message` and `url`. i.e.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/indexname/tweet/00001 -d '{"message": "some message", "url" : "http://someurl.url"}'
```

Is it possible to get the length (or store size) of only the messages in the above mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [script fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html)

```
{
    {
    "query" : {
        ...
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "message_length" : {
            "script" : "doc['message'].value.size()"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No such property: length for class: java.lang.String.
Should I write a script to get length? If so, how?

Comment: It may be that ES won't let you get at it.  I made one more edit that might do the trick.  Try it with length and length()

Comment: value.size() or just size()?

Comment: "doc['message'].value.size()"

Comment: `doc['message'].length` could also work, but ElasticSearch have disabled fielddata on text fields by default (e.g. version >= 5.x), so the above answer no longer works. "courier fetch" shard error in Kibana and "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [message] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead." error on the API.

`doc['message.keyword'].length` also didn't work (in v5.3), as painless scripting doesn't support nested fields.